# pandas series sub-setting by index

Tags: python, pandas, subset, series

Here is my example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,5,6,77,9],'col_2':[6,2,4,2,5]})
df.index = [8,9,10,11,12]
```

This sub-setting is by row order:

```
df.col_1[2:5]
```

returns

```
10     6
11    77
12     9
Name: col_1, dtype: int64
```

while this subsetting is already by index and does not to work:

```
df.col_1[2]
```

returns:

```
KeyError: 2
```

I find it very confusing and am curios what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're statements are ambiguous, therefore it best to explicitly define what you want.

df.col_1[2:5] is working like `df.col_1.iloc[2:5]` using integer location.

Where as df.col[2] is working like `df.col_1.loc[2]` using index label location, hence there is no index labelled 2, so you get the KeyError.

Hence is best to defined whether are are using integer location with `.iloc` or index label location using `.loc`.

See [Pandas Indexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

Comment: I wish this syntax `df.col_1[5]` or `df.col_1[5:7]` simply would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume this is the initial DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_1':[1, 5, 6, 77, 9], 
        'col_2':[6, 2, 4, 2, 5]
        }, 
    index=list('abcde')
    )

df
Out: 
   col_1  col_2
a      1      6
b      5      2
c      6      4
d     77      2
e      9      5
```

The index consists of strings so it is generally obvious what you are trying to do:

- `df['col_1']['b']` You passed a string so you are probably trying to access by label. It returns 5.
- `df['col_1'][1]` You passed an integer so you are probably trying to access by position. It returns 5.
- Same deal with slices: `df['col_1']['b':'d']` uses labels and `df['col_1'][1:4]` uses positions.

When the index is also integer, nothing is obvious anymore.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_1':[1, 5, 6, 77, 9], 
        'col_2':[6, 2, 4, 2, 5]
        }, 
    index=[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    )

df
Out: 
    col_1  col_2
8       1      6
9       5      2
10      6      4
11     77      2
12      9      5
```

Let's say you type `df['col_1'][8]`. Are you trying to access by label or by position? What if it was a slice? Nobody knows. At this point, pandas chooses one of them based on their usage. It is in the end a Series and what distinguishes a Series from an array is its labels so the choice for  `df['col_1'][8]` is labels. Slicing with labels is not that common so pandas is being smart here and using positions when you pass a slice. Is it inconsistent? Yes. Should you avoid it? Yes. This is the main reason `ix` was deprecated.

Explicit is better than implicit so use either `iloc` or `loc` when there is room for ambiguity. `loc` will always raise a KeyError if you try to access an item by position and `iloc` will always raise a KeyError if you try to access by label.